# Using the AWS EMR artifact repository with a build tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, gradle, amazon-emr

I try to use the EMR artifact repository to package the *emrfs-hadoop-assembly* and it's dependencies into my application.

The resources I found, tell me the URL of the Maven repository I have to use but nothing about the actual artifacts inside this repository. The version of the components included in an EMR release is publicly available but I have to guess the *artifactId* and *groupId* for everything that is not a standard dependency (such as hadoop-common). The repository works for dependencies suffixed with `amzn` but I still fail to download the relevant jar.

Can anyone provide information on how to use this Maven repository?

EDIT:

I looked at the *pom.xml* of the jar I want to fetch via Maven/Gradle and got the *artifactId* and *groupId* but the build tool is not able to resolve those.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the more info here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-artifact-repository.html

Add this to your `pom.xml` if emr version you are using is `v5.26.0`

```
<repository>
 <id>emr-5.26.0-artifacts</id>
 <name>EMR 5.26.0 Releases Repository</name>
 <releases>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
 </releases>
 <snapshots>
   <enabled>false</enabled>
 </snapshots>
 <url>https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/us-west-1-emr-artifacts/emr-5.26.0/repos/maven/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: I managed to register the repository already. My problem is with the artifacts inside the repository, not the repository itself.